SIP SDK for Java
I want to implement a small callbot with Java.
I have the same callbot on C++ using pjsip library.
Basically I have a Asterisk server that transfers the call for my callbot, and the user can use DTMF or voice to communicate.
I couldn't find any still maintained SIP library for Java. The closest I could found is jain-sip.
Is there any other SDK/library that I could use for this?
